# How to scale vertices outwards?

Tags: modeling, vertices, extrude, 3d-printing

I've done this before and I can't do it again - either I've triggered some setting that changes how scale (or extrude) works or I've just completely forgotten how to do this. I have the cylinder on the right and need to make it like the one on the left, but the final measurements are rather different, so I can't just scale the one on the left.
[image]
I tried to extrude the vertices on the upper level (on the cylinder on the right), then right click (to break out of the extrude mode) and change to scale so I could scale them inwards. When I do that, I get results like this:
[image]
That looks to me like it's still trying to extrude all the vertices and not like it's trying to scale them.

Have I activated some mode that doesn't let me scale normally? How can I just extrude those top vertices inwards (or outwards if I start from the narrower cylinder)? I tried using I and I got the shape I wanted, but the measurements were off from what they should have been.

Comment: select the face you want to scale, then press `I` for inset and then `E` `Z` to extrude on the z-axis

Comment: if you get this result when you scale it may be because you've chosen the 3D cursor in the Transform Pivot Point panel instead of Median Point for example

Comment: Although Harry's answer is a good solution how to do it (because I'm actually not a fan of insetting through extrude, abort, scale when you have an _Inset_ tool, but I see lots of tutors on YT doing it like that), I still think moonboots is correct as well. If scaling moves your selection over to the side, you've definitely changed the pivot point. By the way, if you do this extrude method for insetting: there is no need for right-clicking to abort the extrude. Just hit E and S directly afterwards to scale.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

0.) In *Edit Mode*, press <kbd>3</kbd> to switch to *Face Select* mode
1.) *Select* or <kbd>LMB</kbd> the face you want to *inset*
2.) Press <kbd>I</kbd> and move then left click
3.) Press <kbd>E</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> to extrude on the *z-axis*

If it doesn't scale as you wanted, undo it and select the face again then press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> *> Cursor to Selected* and then redo those enumerated steps

[image]

Or you can do it starting with the smaller cylinder as follows:

0.) In *Edit Mode*, press <kbd>3</kbd> to switch to *Face Select* mode
1.) *Select* or <kbd>LMB</kbd> the bottom face
2.) Press <kbd>E</kbd> to extrude downwards
3.) Select Face Loop ( <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>LMB</kbd> ) of extruded part
4.) Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> > *Extrude Faces Along Normals*

[image]

Comment: I'm a bit confused. So I would select the top face, and the I and that will let me go from the first image to the 2nd one? I thought I had to select the vertices in Vertex select mode. Sounds like that's the big issue I'm dealing with.

Comment: It's easier in *Face Select* mode but you can also do it in *Vertex Select* mode. Just make sure you select all the vertices on that face (you can do it with `Alt`+`LMB` on one vertex) then press `i`. Yes it should go to the second image as soon as you move your mouse after pressing `i`. You can also input type a specific measurement (like typing 0.5) after pressing `i` then press `Enter`. if you're still having issues, can you share your blend file at https://blend-exchange.com

Comment: @Tango There are some things that might be exclusive for vertices, edges or faces, but in general they are interchangeable. Since the vertices which are connected to edges that form faces are not separate things it is always possible in Blender to switch between modes depending on what is easier to use or fits better for what you want to achieve. Let's say you want to select 50 vertices that form a single n-gon... why select 50 vertices when you can simply click on one face? Or why select two vertices when you can simply click the one edge that's connecting them? :)

Comment: Okay, that works. One question about what can and can't be done. I can use <kbd>I</kbd> and then create the new faces that move from the outside rim toward the inside of the circle, but is there a way I could move the faces outside, expanding from the circle, instead? In other words, instead of starting with the bigger cylinder and making the smaller one on top, is there a way to start with the smaller cylinder and move outwards instead of inwards?

Comment: @Tango yes that's also possible, i updated my answer to include this alternative method as well