# After Extrude > Right Click > Scale, I can't scale only one face

Tags: transforms, extrude, duplicate

I'm new to Blender and found a problem during a tutorial. When I scale, after Extrude > Right Click, both faces get scaled at the same time. I'm sure there's something that I'm doing wrong I just can't figure out what it is.

After a big online search, this answer  [How to scale vertices outwards?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/269170/how-to-scale-vertices-outwards/269176#269176?newreg=1a96e72634294889839a27d89fafe57c)
was the only answer that is more related to the problem I have and that offers a valid workaround so, thank you for that.

Though my problem is solved with the workaround and tips I still would like to figure out why is it happening since, as Gordon mentioned, there are a lot of tutorials using this Extrude > right click > Scale method.

I'm sure there are two faces in place since I can see the face and vertices count on the model but when I choose G or S both move at the same time. I've started a new file to see if I was doing something wrong. And on a clean file, it works as expected. The new extrude resulting face gets scaled inwards.

Why is it happening? What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Joca

[image: Sequence command Extrude > Right Click > Scale]

[image]

Comment: As we aren't sitting in front of your computer looking at your screen and we don't have any idea what tutorial you're watching it's impossible to guess what you've done, You can share your file via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there and add some images of the problem (https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post ) but without those we really can't give you any suggestions.

Comment: Hi John. Thank you for your answer and sorry for not uploading the file. Already done.

Comment: I think it might be that you have Proportional Editing switched on (with a very low radius, so you can't see the circle that indicates falloff) ?

Comment: Robin, that was it! Thank you for your answer and thank you for your time!

Comment: @JocaFaria Good to hear it's sorted.  That's why it's usually so important to be able to see Blender's window in a question. We'd have been able to see if proportional edit was turned on immediately from the icon on the top tool bar. For future reference you can take a snapshot of Blender's window via the Window > save Screenshot menu.

Comment: Duly noted, @JohnEason. Thank you for your help!